# How to pass parameters to WCF in an asynchronous process

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, mvvm, telerik

I am new to this technololgy. I am trying to use MVVM (for the first time). In the View, I have a datepicker bound to a property Calendardate in the ViewModel (this works). The WCF Test Client verifies that GetEncounterTimesAsync() -- no parameters -- works correctly. I have changed the WCF service query to use a datetime parameter. The model was created from the database as an EntityFramework. (Using Telerik Data Access).

I have searched the internet without success. I am not using any web services (as far as I know).

What I have done below fails.

How do I pass a parameter from the UI to WCF and perform a query on the Entity?

If this can not be done, how can a parameterized query be made through WCF to an EntityFramerwork?

I am very confused, any help would be most appreciated.

(My system: Visual Studio 2010, Telerik Data Access)

The ViewModel:

```
public MaintenanceFormViewModel()
    {
        this.Calendardate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void RefreshEncountertimes()
    {
        // manage results when the WCF service returns
        this.serviceClient.GetEncounterTimesCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Encountertimes = e.Result;
        };
        // call the WCF service
        this.serviceClient.GetEncounterTimesAsync(Calendardate);
    }

private DateTime calendardate;
    public DateTime Calendardate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.calendardate;
        }
        set
        {
            this.calendardate = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Calendardate");
            this.RefreshEncountertimes();
        }
    }
```

My WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ChaosService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Encountertime> GetEncounterTimes(DateTime encountertime)
    {
        using (var context = new ChaosModel())
        {
            var query = from et in context.Encountertimes
                        where et.Tencounter.Date == encountertime.Date
                        select et;

            var result = context.CreateDetachedCopy(query.ToList());
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the ServiceReference?

Comment: How do I update the ServiceReference?

Comment: It is very basic, just Google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the ServiceReferences in your client project.
Right click on the `ChaosService`.
Select Update Service Reference.